# how to setup a global contact list in exchange 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003, outlook, outlook-2003

Users should be able to create, view, edit and delete contacts from the list.

If this is possible,  could someone help me out? I can't seem to find much info on the subject.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/MF018.html

Comment: I'd +1 if there were a quick summary of the steps - never know when a howto site is going to rearrange their content.

Comment: I agree but I figured a C+P was safe considering the article was from 2003 :)

Comment: Curious, does anyone know what privileges I need to create public folders for this tutorial? Because outlook is saying I do not have the correct privileges. I have access to all admin privileges as far as I can tell...

Comment: Does your account have the admin privileges or are you using a separate admin account to do work with Exchange? This link may be of assistance to you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823018

Comment: @DKNUCKLES, just a heads-up. Some people around here tend to downvote answers that consist of just a link, as they feel you should provide more details. You'll also get more upvotes when details are supplied.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up John...I'm still relatively new around here so I appreciate the courtesy!